# What input can I give to cause a buffer overflow that results in exact changes in another variable?

Tags: c, security, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow

Let's say my goal is to input something that can change the value of num from -200 to 400. How should I go about doing this?

```
char letters[20];
long num = -200;
puts("Here I want to enter a word with more letters than 20 to cause an overflow");
gets(letters);
printf("num: %d", num);
```

I'm trying out this code snippet above, and purposely using gets instead of fgets to see how gets can be exploited.

Below is a sample input and output, my thought process is I want to overflow the buffer by exceeding the 20 character limit, then making everything else spill over to the `num` variable:

```
> Here I want to enter a word with more letters than 20 to cause an overflow
> aaaabbbbccccdddd600
> num: -200
> stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated 
> Aborted (core dumped)
```

As seen, my `num` variable does not change and I get this warning. From google my understanding is this is a mechanism intended to protect against overflow. How can I bypass this? Thanks!

Comment: First of all, the compiler might add padding between variables. Secondly, the compiler can place variables in any order it likes. You need to know *exactly* what your compiler is doing with the code to be able to successfully "hack" the program.

Comment: Ah, I see. Can you point me in the right direction as to how I may be able to do that?

Comment: Being able to read the actual generated assembly code should help.

Comment: I see. So you're saying I need assembly knowledge to be able to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can study the assembly code generated by different compilers with different options on [Matt Godbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/rrha9rs1j).

For the hack to work, the compiler must instantiate the `letters` array and the `num` variable on the stack, in this order. This is the case for gcc with optimisations disabled, and they are 24 bytes apart because of padding. Entering a string longer than 24 bytes will corrupt the value of `num` on this particular instance.

Note however that gcc with optimisations enabled does not use stack memory for `num` and passes `200` to `printf` directly.

Note also that clang with optimisations disabled instantiates `letters` at `[rbp-32]` and `num` at `[rbp-40]`, before `letters` so buffer overflow from `gets` will not corrupt `num`, but may corrupt the return address and cause worse consequences, as is also the case for most compilers and options, as you observed in your test case.

Here is the test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// prototype for obsolete function
int gets(char *);

int main() {
    char letters[20];
    long num = -200;
    puts("Here I want to enter a word with more letters than 20 to cause an overflow");
    gets(letters);
    printf("num: %d", num);
    return 0;
}
```

The assembly for **gcc -O0**:

```asm
.LC0:
        .string "Here I want to enter a word with more letters than 20 to cause an overflow"
.LC1:
        .string "num: %d"
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 32
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], -200
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    puts
        lea     rax, [rbp-32]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    gets
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     rsi, rax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
```

The assembly for **gcc -O2**:

```asm
.LC0:
        .string "Here I want to enter a word with more letters than 20 to cause an overflow"
.LC1:
        .string "num: %d"
main:
        sub     rsp, 40
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    puts
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    gets
        mov     rsi, -200
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 40
        ret
```

The assembly for **clang -O0**:

```asm
main:                                   # @main
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 48
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 4], 0
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 40], -200
        lea     rdi, [rip + .L.str]
        call    puts@PLT
        lea     rdi, [rbp - 32]
        call    gets@PLT
        mov     rsi, qword ptr [rbp - 40]
        lea     rdi, [rip + .L.str.1]
        mov     al, 0
        call    printf@PLT
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 48
        pop     rbp
        ret
.L.str:
        .asciz  "Here I want to enter a word with more letters than 20 to cause an overflow"

.L.str.1:
        .asciz  "num: %d"
```